# How to reset an svg animation to its initial state?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG animation similar to this:

```js
function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector('#anim-width').beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate
      id="anim-width"
      attributeName="width"
      from="10"
      to="80"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze"
      begin="click"
    />
    
    <animate
      attributeName="height"
      from="10"
      to="80"
      begin="anim-width.end + 0s"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>

<br/>

<button onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```

What I want to achieve is the red box starts from 10 by 10, when clicking the button, the width expands from 10 to 80, then the height expands to 80 after the width animation is done.

It works fine for the first playback, but when clicking the button again the height starts from 80 instead of 10, how do I reset everthing to its intial state and replay the entire animation?

I tried adding `document.querySelector('#box').setAttribute('height', '10');` in the `startAnimation()` function but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm adding an element `<set>` inside the rect and I'm starting the set element inside the function `function startAnimation()`

The `<set>` element ìs a maner of setting the value of an attribute (height in this case), like an animation with duration 0.

```js
function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector("#set").beginElement();
  document.querySelector("#anim-width").beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate id="anim-width" attributeName="width" from="10" to="80" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="click" />

    <animate id="anim-height" attributeName="height" from="10" to="80" begin="anim-width.end + 0s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />

    <set id="set" attributeName="height" to="10"></set>
  </rect>
</svg>

<br />

<button onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```

Comment: Didn't know there's a `<set>` tag, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, do you know how to stop all animations? When I click it again before the first animation is finished, it seems two copies of the same animation are playing simultaneously.

Comment: please take a look at `endElement()` & `endElementAt()` Also take a look at `pauseAnimations()`

Comment: `endElement()` will  probably not be useful here because you are triggering one animation at the end of another.  So ending an animation will just set the next one going..

One option would be to disablie the start button until the animation ends.  See my updated answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is just to have an `<animate>` element that starts the animation by resetting the height.

```js
document.querySelector("#anim-height").addEventListener("endEvent", enableButton);

function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector("#start-btn").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector("#anim-start").beginElement();
}


function enableButton()
{
  document.querySelector("#start-btn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate id="anim-start" attributeName="height" to="10" dur="0.01s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
    <animate id="anim-width" attributeName="width" from="10" to="80" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="anim-start.end + 0s" />
    <animate id="anim-height" attributeName="height" from="10" to="80" begin="anim-width.end + 0s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>

<br />

<button id="start-btn" onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```